# Passing an array attribute of an object as a React component prop throws an exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand why I can not pass an array attribute of a data object into a Component as a prop. Think this is a fundamental understanding question of how React works, and/or the pitfalls in a case like this...any insight is appreciated!

Context: I'm working on a Show page for a Meeting in React. This Show page will show elements like "title", "description", as well as iterate through a list of "agenda_items".

The data comes from a single JSON API response. "agenda_items" is a nested array within the data structure.

```
{
  data: {
    id: 2,
    title: "Example title",
    description: "Example description",
    agenda_items: [
      {
        id: 5,
        title: "Topic 1"
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: "Topic 2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The below implementation works. I am setting `meeting` and `agenda_items` separately with `React.useState()`, even though `agenda_items` is theoretically accessible via `meeting.agenda_items`.

```
const Meeting = () => {
  const [meeting, setMeeting] = React.useState([]);
  const [agenda_items, setAgendaItems] = React.useState([]);

  const handleFetchMeeting = React.useCallback(() => {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(result => {
        setMeeting(result.data);
        setAgendaItems(result.data.agenda_items);
      })
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleFetchMeeting();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{meeting.title}</h1>
      <AgendaList list={agenda_items} />
    </div>
  );
}

const AgendaList = ({ list }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Agenda</h3>
      {list.map(item => (
        <Item 
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, if I instead try to pass `meeting.agenda_items` into the `<AgendaList>` as a param, it throws an exception. I would've thought these two implementations are equivalent, but it seems not?

```
...

return (
    <div>
      <h1>{meeting.title}</h1>
      <AgendaList list={meeting.agenda_items} />
    </div>
  );
)

//INSTEAD OF
/*
return (
    <div>
      <h1>{meeting.title}</h1>
      <AgendaList list={agenda_items} />
    </div>
  );
)
*/
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at AgendaList (Meeting.jsx:52)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14972)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17734)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18935)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3922)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3971)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4031)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23780)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22616)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22553)
```

How is it that React has no problem with finding/rendering `{meeting.title}`, but then calls `{meeting.agenda_items}` undefined?

Is this error happening the first time the component renders, before the async data call has completed?

Comment: If you don't use separate state variables, `meeting` is `[]` initially. Therefore `meeting.agenda_items` is `undefined`, which causes the error. You can fix this by using `const [meeting, setMeeting] = React.useState({ agenda_items: [] });` (or by using `{list && list.map(item => (`)

Comment: Thank you, perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
const AgendaList = ({ list }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Agenda</h3>
      {list.map(item => (
        <Item 
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

to :

```
const AgendaList = ({ list }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Agenda</h3>
      {list?.map(item => (
        <Item 
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

// if your code has support for optional chaining
```

OR:

```
const AgendaList = ({ list }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Agenda</h3>
      {list.length ? list.map(item => (
        <Item 
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
        />
      )) : <></>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`meeting.agenda_items` might not be available as at the time <AgendaList ... /> is rendered. So what is basically happening is that you're mapping through probably non-existing (in this case `undefined`) data at that point. Since the value would be updated once the data is ready and the component would get the update, this new option tells the component to only map through `list` if it has a length since you're expecting an object (array) in this case.

You could go further by adding a loader as the other option when the `list` is not yet ready or handle a case when the `list` is actually empty also.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. I will look into a loader as well.

Comment: I also found a separate fix that helped me understand this better, which is by setting `agenda_items` to an empty array in the initial state of the `meeting` object.

`const [meeting, setMeeting] = React.useState({'agenda_items': []});`

Comment: Yh, that also works. Remember `meeting` only had a value of this `{}` originally, meaning any property of `meeting` you were trying to access if `meeting` hasn't been updated would be `undefined`. What you did there was to set the initial value of `agenda_items` to an `array` which comes with a `length` property in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

On first render the axios request will not have completed. At that point you have set default values as arrays.

`{meeting.title}` will simply evaluate to undefined and be ignored in rendering.

Similarly `meeting.agenda_items` will also be undefined and so `list.map()` will be equivalent to `undefined.map()` and will throw an error.

When you pass just `agenda_items` it is already defined as an empty array in `useState()` and list.map() will be equivalent to `[].map()` which is valid